# Generate two different random numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, windows, if-statement, random

I'm using Excel for Office 365. I would like to generate either a number between 10 and 12 if a give cell (H5) equals 20 or a number between 1 and 12 if H5 is any other number. Here's my code"

`=IF(H5="20", RANDBETWEEN(10, 12),  RANDBETWEEN($B$3, $C$3))`

Currently the code just returns a random number between 1 and 12 no matter what.

Comment: Remove quotes and just write 20, `=IF(H5=20, RANDBETWEEN(10, 12),  RANDBETWEEN($B$3, $C$3))` I have tested it works. Numbers should not be within quotes, only Strings text needs to be within quotes.

Comment: When you write `H5="20"` i.e. within quotes it gives you `FALSE` always, as it reads `20` as **Text** while when you write `H5=20` i.e. without quotes, it reads `20` as **Number** and hence gives you `TRUE`, so then the logic works when `TRUE` and not works when `FALSE`. For your own understanding, goto `Formulas Tab`, under `Formula Auditing Group` click on `Evaluate` you know how it works and understand the difference.